# CSS media query to change font-size in html selector not working

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass, scss-mixins

I'm using the 62.5% trick to set my font-size on different screen sizes. The letters look too small on big screens so I want to increase it to 80% font-size using a min-width media query but for some reason, this does not work at all. Am I doing something wrong?
I'm using sass and this file is within a `_themes.scss` file

**edit:** When I look at the inspector, the media query is crossed out and says "**unknown property name**"

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  @media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    font-size: 80%;
  }
}
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your media query needs to exist on its own, outside the initial definition, not inside it.

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  
}
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

  @media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    html {
      font-size: 80%;
    }
  }
```